# ng-if controller function to show directive on multiple location path

Tags: angularjs

how can i move a logic from an ng-if from html and turn it into a function in the controller?

```
<menu ng-if="location.path() === '/salad' || location.path() ==='/main'"></menu>
```

controller:`???`

I try to give a go but this didnt work:

html:`<menu ng-if="menuItem()"></menu>`

controller:

```
$scope.menuItem = function() {

  return menuItem === $location.path('/salad') || $location.path('/main');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your use of the directive, although it is preferable to use ng-if with an expression rather than a function, since the function will now evaluate on every digest cycle.

I think your error is actually coming from the way you've written your expression in menuItem.

Try:

```
$scope.menuItem = function () {
  return ($location.path() === '/salad' || $location.path() ==='/main')
}
```

Comment: i just tried your suggestion but the directive <menu> did not show when i changed the URL  to /salad or /main.  Does is matter within the <menu> directive I have more ng-if inside it?  Those ng-if also relies showing elements based on location too.

Comment: Using ng-if to show based on route definitely isn't the best practice.  I'm assuming you've done something like:

$routeProvider.otherwise({
  templateUrl: 'something.html',
  controller: 'somecontroller'
});

I would re-evaluate the way you're doing your routing.  Take a look at [routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).